# Output other than .txt

Tags: text, output

I'm looking to build a simple program that will simply modify existing output files from an other program so I don't have to open the program and enter a bunch of data the long way. This program is very specific to my domain and has an extension named .wcc. However, when I change the extension of one of these output files to .txt, I get half gibberish :

> ÿÿ   WPointÿÿ  WPolygonÿÿ   WQuadrilateralÿÿ  WMemberDataÿÿ
>     WLoadÿÿ   WLStandardMembersÿÿ  WLSavedDesignSettingsÿÿ  WLSavedFormatSettingsÿÿ   WLSavedViewSettingsÿÿ   WLSavedProjectSettingsÿÿ  WLSavedSettingsÿÿ  WLSavedLoadSettingsÿÿ  WLSavedDefaultSettingsÿÿ   WLineÿÿ  WProductÿÿ     WBeamDataÿÿ  WColumnDataÿÿ 
>    WJoistDataÿÿ 
>    WWallStudDataÿÿ  WSupportingMemberDataÿÿ  WSavedAnalysisSettingsÿÿ  WSavedGravityDesignSettingsÿÿ   WSavedPreferencesSettingsÿÿ  WNotchÿÿ  WIJoistÿÿ  WFloorCWC37                       ÀAE        LumberS-P-F   No.1/No.2   @  À@        lumwall.cww      ÿÿÿÿ1.2.3.1.Mur_1_EX-D                                  ÿÿÿÿÿÿ    B  Cÿÿ    B  C                       €?         4C  4C                                   Neige    @F @F                   ÈC               ÿÿÿ
>   WLStandardMembersÿÿ "

There are also musical notes and perpendicular signs which I can't copy paste here. I can sorta read the text, but still not enough to make modifications via txt file. What type of file could this be? Is it even possible to do what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: Your file is a binary file and if you try to modify it using text file functions (or plain text editors) you'll corrupt it. Those 'strange' characters are likely length prefixes, data delimiters or other structural elements of the file format, whatever it is.

Comment: Those musical symbols, as well as the abundance of `ÿ` characters you are seeing here, *plus* any number (unknown!) of characters you cannot see because they cannot be displayed in a plain text form -- think "binary zero" -- suggests this is a binary format file. Do Not Treat As Text. You need a specific decoder/encoder for it.

Comment: Stack overflow is for questions about programming.  "What are the contents of this file" is not a programming question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am surprised that you are trying to open a `.wcc` file as a text file (it's contents - as you will see - don't lend themselves to being converted to such a file type); however, the attempt to open the file as a `.txt` file seems to be specific to your domain.

I noticed part of your question is as follows: "What type of file could this be?"

You are right in thinking that the .wcc file is a rather obscure file type - we don't think about that file type a lot (or are not conscious of it existing). A `.wcc` file is a WinCam 2000 Cache file that allows WinCam 2000 movies to be previewed in the slide browser - these were often generated by older WinCam 2000 screen recording and editing programs.

Again, the file extension is very rare these days (a Google search only returns ~700 results). But, it appears you have a program that is producing the file, which - as you are saying - "is quite specific to your domain". You may be out of luck with regard to opening them for modification purposes.

Supposedly, you can covert `.wac` files to `.wav` files, which are much more relevant to today's technology (**and definitely alterable from code**); however, without knowing the purpose of the file, e.g. what you are trying to do with the file domain-side, I can't say that this will suit your needs.

Also, the above comments are "correct": changing a file extension will not convert the file to the file extension type. Typically, converters - like a simple software - are needed to convert files.